# Space between figure and caption RMarkdown PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I need to reduce the space between a caption and figure in my RMarkdown PDF document. I am using `bookdown`. Following the example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45990/how-can-i-modify-vertical-space-between-figure-and-caption), I tried setting the length above and below the caption using the Latex command `\setlength{}`, but to no avail. MWE:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
- \usepackage{floatrow}
- \floatsetup{capposition=top}
- \floatplacement{figure}{H}
- \captionsetup{position=above, aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Including Plots

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-25pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-25pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Caption"}
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(pressure)
```
````

Which yields:

[image]

Is there another way to get around this spacing issue?

Comment: A lot of that is part of the plot itself, because the margins leave space for a title, but there isn't one. Reduce them, e.g. with `par(mar = c(5, 4, 0, 2) + 0.1)` before plotting.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire, but my concern is that `\setlength{}` isn't doing anything at all. I have updated my MWE to include no margins for the plot, but am still unable to adjust the distance between the figure and caption.